# Ctrl+shift+down not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, keyboard

Ctrl+shift+down works in IE and Chrome to select the entire text, but has no effect in Firefox atleast version 27, is it that it is using the key combination for other purpose. Can I enable it for my website, so that if someone visits my website using firefox, the above shortcut works. There are alternate shortcuts but due to some reasons I need the above shortcut.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+End should do the same thing and works for all major browsers.

Comment: @Chirag64 I need this for simulation purpose, the above combination